# UIActivityViewController for Facebook, Twitter and Instagram ONLY

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to get a UIActivityViewController for presenting only the options for Facebook, Twitter and Instagram. So far I have done:

```
    let shareText = "Hello, world!"

    let image = UIImage(named: "TheImage")
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText,image], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
                                                    UIActivityType.airDrop,
                                                    UIActivityType.assignToContact,
                                                    UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard,
                                                    UIActivityType.mail,
                                                    UIActivityType.message,
                                                    UIActivityType.openInIBooks,
                                                    UIActivityType.print,
                                                    UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll
                                                    ]
    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

But the UIActivityViewController is still giving me unwanted options.

I also thought to get and approach with NSExtensionItem but I am not sure about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are option available for Facebook and Twitter, You need to just add excludedActivityTypes. You have missing it.

Instagram option still not available in activity types

```
let image = UIImage(named: "TheImage")
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText,image], applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.addToReadingList,
                                               .airDrop,
                                               .assignToContact,
                                               .copyToPasteboard,
                                               .mail,
                                               .message,
                                               .openInIBooks,
                                               .print,
                                               .saveToCameraRoll,
                                               .postToWeibo,
                                               .copyToPasteboard,
                                               .saveToCameraRoll,
                                               .postToFlickr,
                                               .postToVimeo,
                                               .postToTencentWeibo,
                                               .markupAsPDF
]    

present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

I hope this will help you.

There are following list of Activity types available.

```
extension UIActivityType {


    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public static let postToFacebook: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public static let postToTwitter: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public static let postToWeibo: UIActivityType // SinaWeibo

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public static let message: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public static let mail: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public static let print: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public static let copyToPasteboard: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public static let assignToContact: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public static let saveToCameraRoll: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public static let addToReadingList: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public static let postToFlickr: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public static let postToVimeo: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public static let postToTencentWeibo: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public static let airDrop: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    public static let openInIBooks: UIActivityType

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    public static let markupAsPDF: UIActivityType
}
```

Comment: Also in the extension I get the error "'static var' declaration requires an initializer expression or getter/setter specifier"

Comment: Ohhh, yeah.
Sorry.. My misunderstanding I will update answer.

Comment: @ReimondHill, Please check now. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Apple** provides support for some of the default `UIActivityTypes` that includes both `Facebook` and `Twitter` as required by you.

You can get a complete list of `UIActivityTypes` here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivitytype

By default, all the `UIActivityTypes` appear in the `UIActivityController`. The activities you don't want to appear in the `UIActivityController` an be added in the `exclude list`, i.e

```
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.postToFlickr, .postToVimeo]
```

Also, whenever an `App` that includes a **`Share App Extension`** is installed on the device, it is also added to the `UIActivityController`.

***Example*:**

**WhatsApp**. Whenever you install WhatsApp on your device, it will appear as a `Share App Extension` in the `UIActivityController`. 
You cannot remove them but can only hide them from the `UIActivityController's` **More** option.

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Answer (score 1):

As of now (march 2019), Instagram share option will only appear if you set an image and only that image on the activityItems. If you add a TEXT or URL object there as well the Instagram option will not show up.

Twitter, on the otehr hand would accept a TEXT and an IMAGE, but if you pass an URL too it will not show up as an option as well

Comment: just for the record this is no longer the case (confirmed today)